# Show only 1 tab onload from gallery

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to display only one tab from the gallery tabs, because right now all tabs are beeing displayed when the page loads.

Here is my entire code if someone can show me an example of how to make only 1 tab visible when the page loads would be great!

```js
(function() {
 
 var thumbsSpacing = 25;

 $('.filter').css('margin-bottom', thumbsSpacing + 'px');
 $('.thumbnail').addClass('showThumb').addClass('fancybox').attr('rel', 'group');

 $('a.sortLink').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('a.sortLink').addClass('selected');
  $(this).removeClass('selected');

  var category = $(this).data('category');
  filterThumbs(category);
 });

 positionThumbs();
 setInterval(checkViewport, 750);

 function checkViewport() {

  var photosWidth = $('.photos').width(),
   thumbsContainerWidth = $('.thumbnail_wrap').width(),
   thumbnailWidth = $('a.thumbnail:first-child').outerWidth();

  if ( photosWidth < thumbsContainerWidth ) {
   positionThumbs();
  }

  if ( (photosWidth - thumbnailWidth) > thumbsContainerWidth ) {
   positionThumbs();
  }
 }

 function filterThumbs(category) {
  
  $('a.thumbnail').each(function() {
   var thumbCategory = $(this).data('categories');

   if ( category === 'all' ) {
    $(this).addClass('showThumb').removeClass('hideThumb').attr('rel', 'group');
   } else {
    if ( thumbCategory.indexOf(category) !== -1 ) {
     $(this).addClass('showThumb').removeClass('hideThumb').attr('rel', 'group');
    } else {
     $(this).addClass('hideThumb').removeClass('showThumb').attr('rel', 'none');
    }
   }
  });

  positionThumbs();

 }

 function positionThumbs() {

  $('a.thumbnail.hideThumb').animate({
   'opacity': 0
  }, 500, function() {
   $(this).css({
    'display': 'none',
    'top': '0px',
    'left': '0px'
   });
  });

  var containerWidth = $('.photos').width(),
   thumbRow = 0,
   thumbColumn = 0,
   thumbWidth = $('.thumbnail img:first-child').outerWidth() + thumbsSpacing,
   thumbHeight = $('.thumbnail img:first-child').outerHeight() + thumbsSpacing,
   maxColumns = Math.floor( containerWidth / thumbWidth );

  $('a.thumbnail.showThumb').each(function(index){
   var remainder = ( index%maxColumns ) / 100,
    maxIndex = 0;

   if( remainder === 0 ) {
    if( index !== 0 ) {
     thumbRow += thumbHeight;
    }
    thumbColumn = 0;
   } else {
    thumbColumn += thumbWidth;
   }

   $(this).css('display', 'block').animate({
    'opacity': 1,
    'top': thumbRow + 'px',
    'left': thumbColumn + 'px'
   }, 500);

   var newWidth = thumbColumn + thumbWidth,
    newHeight = thumbRow + thumbHeight;
   $('.thumbnail_wrap').css({
    'width': newWidth + 'px',
    'height': newHeight + 'px'
   });
  });

  findFancyBoxLinks();
 }

 function findFancyBoxLinks() {

  $('a.fancybox[rel="group"]').fancybox({
   'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
   'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
   'titlePosition' : 'over',
   'speedIn' : 500,
   'overlayColor' : '#000',
   'padding' : 0,
   'overlayOpacity' : .75
  });
 }

})();
```

```css
p {
 margin: 0px 0px 1em 0px;
}

a {
 outline: none;
}

.title {
 width: 70%;
 margin: 0px auto 40px;
}

.title h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 36px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #FCFAE1;
}

.gallery {
 width: 97%;
 margin: 0;
}

.filter {
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 padding: 2em 0 2em 1em;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #a90000;
}

 .filter span {
  padding: 0 :; 0 0;
  font-family: Georgia, cursive;
  font-style: italic;
 }

 .filter a {
  color: #a90000;
  font-size: .95em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  background: url('../img/unchecked.png') no-repeat 0px 3px;
 }

 .filter a:hover {
  color: #B9121B;
 }

 .filter a.selected {
  color: #B9121B;
  background: url('../img/checked.png') no-repeat 0px 3px;
 }

.wrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 2000px;
 position: relative;
}

a.thumbnail {
 position: absolute;
}

a.thumbnail img {
 width: 190px;
 height: 170px;
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 padding: 2px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #BD8D46;
}

 a.thumbnail img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #4C1B1B;
 }

.clear_floats {
 clear: both;
 line-height: 1px;
}

/* Horizontal Media Queries */
@media screen and (min-height: 50px) and (max-height: 520px) {
 .title h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-height: 521px) and (max-height: 700px) {
 .title h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
 }
}


/* Vertical Media Queries */
@media screen and (min-width: 50px) and (max-width: 500px) {
 .title h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
 }

 .gallery {
  width: auto;
 }

 .filter span {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .filter a {
  display: block;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 960px) {
 .title h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
 }

 .filter span {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .filter a {
  display: block;
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 961px) {
 .filter span {
  padding-right: 20px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="gallery">
   <div class="filter">
    <div>
     <a href="#" class="sortLink selected" data-category="sec">Sectional doors</a>
     <a href="#" class="sortLink1" data-category="rol">Roller doors</a>
     <a href="#" class="sortLink1" data-category="fly">flywing</a>
     <a href="#" class="sortLink1" data-category="pp">patatos</a>
     <a href="#" class="sortLink1" data-category="alu">aluminium</a>
     <a href="#" class="sortLink1" data-category="oth">other</a>
     <div class="clear_floats"></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="photos">
    
    <div class="wrap">

     <a href="photos/sec/1.jpg" class="thumbnail" data-categories="rol" title="секционна гаражна врата">
      <img src="photos/sec/1.jpg" alt="секционна гаражна врата">
     </a>
     <a href="photos/sec/2.jpg" class="thumbnail" data-categories="oth" title="секционна гаражна врата">
      <img src="photos/sec/2.jpg" alt="секционна гаражна врата">
     </a>
     </div><!-- .thumbnail_wrap end -->

   </div><!-- .photos end -->

  </div
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you to move your complete code in here.. There are snippet feature on Stackoverflow. Just click on `<>` icon on editor toolbar.

Comment: just hide all the other tabs using css except one tab and then use jquery for displaying them

Comment: could you show me an example?